# YII ajax validation on press key(while typing)

Tags: yii

After enabling Ajax Validation:

```
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
```

Generally Yii validate after focus out. Is there any way that we can apply validation to an input field while pressing key or typing the text.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you disabled ajax validation by this code. Change it to `true` to enable it.

To use other validation triggers, there's some properties in `clientOptions`, like:

- `validationDelay` -  integer, the number of milliseconds that an AJAX validation should be delayed after an input is changed
- `validateOnSubmit` -  boolean, whether to perform AJAX validation when the form is being submitted
- `validateOnChange` - boolean, whether to trigger an AJAX validation each time when an input's value is changed
- `validateOnType` - boolean, whether to trigger an AJAX validation each time when the user presses a key

`validateOnType` is what youre looking for, but remember to set proper `validationDelay`.

Sample:

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnType' => true,
    )
)); ?>
```